# Question about using CSS with EasyTabs 5.0

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, css

Not sure if this would be the right place, but I have a question about the EasyTabs 5.0 solution for SharePoint 2010. The author's website (www.pathtosharepoint.com) appears to be down at the moment or I'd ask there.

My site template is built out of DVWPs that recreate the OOTB SharePoint 2010 interface. Each DVWP is tied back to a master list and used conditional statements in the XSLT to determine what components are visible (based on Yes/No questions in the list, which users can easily edit).

I am attempting to hide a tabbed webpart but can't seem to hide the tab. For example, if a user selects NO for the column @ShowReportsTab, my conditional XSLT renders a section of a table that contains CSS. With that CSS, I can easily hide the entire MSOZoneCell for that particular webpart. Since the EasyTabs are generated separately via script, the tab still shows up, though - it just shows nothing if you click on it.

I assume the easiest solution would be add a check to the script so that the tab doesn't display if the content of the actual webpart is empty... but I have no idea how to do that.

Or, on the other hand, is there a way to hide an individual tab by name?

Comment: There are a couple flags to close this, I've left it open and pinged Christophe to the thread for visibility. Perhaps some code might help others find a fix to your issue.

Comment: @PirateEric I'm here, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in responding - I had notifications going to the wrong email.

I finally figured out that when the tabs are generated during the page render, each tab is assigned an ID that corresponds to its webpart. For example, if the webpart has an ID of WebPartWPQ5, then the tab has an ID of etWPQ5.

Using that, I was able to hide both the webpart content and the tab using CSS. To get the desired behavior I used a hidden DVWP with conditional statements to apply the CSS according to which option was selected on the SharePoint list. As long as the order/IDs of the webparts don't change from site to site (which they shouldn't), I'm golden.

It definitely wasn't a problem with EasyTabs, in fact I think EasyTabs is one of the best things ever made for SharePoint. Thanks Christophe!

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the Easy Tabs solution.

First, none of my sites seems to be down at the moment. If something is not working properly, you are welcome to post the link in the comments here, and I'll take a look.

The Easy Tabs do not create tabs for hidden Web Parts, so if you apply the css before running the Easy Tabs script it should work.

Comment: Answered my own question, so no worries. The webparts are normally visible, but I wanted to dynamically hide them based on a user-selected value in a SP list.